# How does one create Microsoft Management console(MMC) snap-in in Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, mmc

Are there an wizard or templates in delphi 2009 to write a MMC console ?

**EDIT**:

Colin Wilson components look great thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [MMC Snap-In Framework for Delphi 7](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d7mmcexpert.htm) by [Colin Wilson](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/delphi.htm). Comes with packages to install and full source code. Might be worth a look.

**Edit**: As Marco points out, there is a Delphi 2009 section of Colin's site. [This link](http://www.btinternet.com/~wilsoncpw/d12componentpackages.zip) is a download to the 2009 version of his components, which contains an updated MMC Snap-In Framework.

Comment: Just browse to the main site and then choose delphi. Then you can choose between sites for various Delphi versions, including 2009

Comment: All links are dead. Is there a mirror of the Delphi 2009 version?

Answer (score 0):

There's also another implementation. It has been published in the "Toolbox Magazin" (a german developer magazine) issue 6'08, page 76. The title is "Eingeschnappte Manager", it also comes with full source on the enclosed CD/DVD.

Slight caveat: As one might notice, the article is of course written in german ...

Have fun,
JensG